# Angular ReactiveFrom subscribe on valueChanges gives [object Object]

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a small angular webform with only 1 dropdown field which is declared in my component.html as a `formControlName="serviceName".`

Dropdown details:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
      <label for="serviceName">Select the Service</label>
      <select class="form-control" formControlName="serviceName" id="serviceName">
        <option *ngFor="let service of srvNames; let i = index" [value]="service">{{ service.ServiceName }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

In my component I have an array declared  `srvNames: any[];` and this array is being populated via an http call to a service.

Users can use the dropdown and select different values, the values are shown in my webpage.
With get('serviceName').valueChanges and subscribe I want to keep track of the changes.

```
this.servicesForm.get('serviceName').valueChanges
      .subscribe(
        (value) => {
          console.log(value);
        }
      );
```

When I console.log the value from the subscribe I see that I am getting back [object Object]

But When I console.log my array I see the values:

```
0:{ServiceName: "PhdTimeSeriesVS"}
1:{ServiceName: "Product"}
length:2
__proto__:Array(0)
```

Can somebody help me?
Thanks,
Lino

Comment: You have in your code <option [value]="service"..>. Or you want say <option [value]="service.serviceID"..> - your "serviceName" get the value of "service.serviceID" - or you want say <option [ngValue]="service" -then your "serviceName will be an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning an object :

```
{ServiceName: "PhdTimeSeriesVS"}
```

And in your select, you pass that object as the value

```
<option *ngFor="let service of srvNames; let i = index" [value]="service">
```

Change that to passe the value of the given key :

```
<option *ngFor="let service of srvNames; let i = index" [value]="service.ServiceName">
```